# How do i get output on html using django?

Tags: python, django

I want get "First Click 1" by click on "First Click" button and "Second Click 2" by click on "Second Click" button.
Here is my code.
my templates is test.html

```
<html>
<form action="get">
<input type="submit" value="First Click" name="first">
<input type="submit" value="Second Click" name="second">
</form>
<div>
First Click {{op0}}
Second Click {{op1}}
</div>
</html>
```

views.py is

```
def analytics(request):
  if(request.GET.get('first')):
    return render(request, 'test.html',{"op0":'1')})
  elif(request.GET.get('second')):
    return render(request, 'test.html',{"op1":'2')})'
```

Current output - when i am clicking on "First Click" button then i am getting "First Click 1".

Actual output - i want to get "First Click 1" by "First Click" button and "Second Click 2" by "Second Click"
    I created onclick event inside submit button then call the method but it was not working.
Thanks in advance

Comment: if request.GET.get == 'first':

Comment: It is not working. I am getting result "First Click Second Click".

Comment: Its not working because you have basic errors in your code `{"op0": '1')})` You have an extra `)`